# Type with no linkage used to declare function with linkage

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that takes as a parameter a pointer to a type I created with `typedef` called `NodeType`. I dimly understand that `typedef` names don't have linkage. I am not sure why I would get the following error when both instances of the type `NodeType` appear to be in the same translation unit.

Here is The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    typedef struct NodeTag{
            char* Airport;
            NodeTag * Link;                
            } NodeType;


    //Declare print function
    void printList(NodeType *);

    void printList(NodeType * L){
        //set N to point to the first element of L
        NodeType * N = L;         

        //if the list is empty we want it to print ()
        printf("( ");
        //while we are not at the Link member of the last NodeType
        while(N != NULL){
        //get the Airport value printed
            printf("%s", N->Airport);
            //advance N
            N= N->Link;
            if(N != NULL){
            printf(", ");
            }
            else{
             //do nothing
            }
         }

        printf(")");   
    }

return 0;
}
```

This is the Error I run into:

```
linkedlists.c: In function 'int main()':
linkedlists.c: error: type 'NodeType {aka main()::NodeTag} with no linkage used
to declare function 'void printList(NodeType*) with linkage [-fpermissive]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: types never have linkage, indepently from the fact that you alias them trough a typedef or not. What compiler is telling you that?

Comment: MinGW. I called g++ from the DOS terminal. Is that legit?

Comment: You are using a C++ compiler for your C code. C does not even support functions inside functions. Use `gcc`. The error message is curious though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `printList` function is defined within the body of `main`, which is confusing the compiler.  Move `printList` outside the body of `main` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct NodeTag{
        char* Airport;
        NodeTag * Link;                
        } NodeType;


//Declare print function
void printList(NodeType *);

int main(){

    return 0;
}

void printList(NodeType * L){
    //set N to point to the first element of L
    NodeType * N = L;         

    //if the list is empty we want it to print ()
    printf("( ");
    //while we are not at the Link member of the last NodeType
    while(N != NULL){
    //get the Airport value printed
        printf("%s", N->Airport);
        //advance N
        N= N->Link;
        if(N != NULL){
        printf(", ");
        }
        else{
         //do nothing
        }
     }

    printf(")");   
}
```

After you've done this and got it to compile, you'll need to figure out how and where to call `printList` from within `main`.

Comment: Is the aliasing of NodeTag with NodeType not equivalent to a definition?

Answer (score 0):

You cant declare your function inside main function. Put the function prototype and declaration outside of the main loop. The function prototype (`void printList(NodeType *);`) should be declared before the function is is actually used. Also declare your structure outside of main and before your function.

You also have a mistake in your typedef

```
       typedef struct NodeTag{
        char* Airport;
        NodeTag * Link; <-- missing struct prefix              
        } NodeType;
```