# C++ enum syntax

Tags: c++, enums

After I declare

```
enum color {red, blue, green};
```

is there any difference between

```
color a=blue;
```

and

```
enum color a=blue;
```

Comment: More of a C thing, really. It's the same deal as `struct`.

Comment: `color a=blue;` won't work if you've done something like: `enum color{blue} color;`. In that case you need `enum color a=blue;` to distinguish between the object and the type. Of course you should simply not overload the enum name this way.

Answer (score 9):

```
enum MyEnumType { ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA };

enum MyEnumType x;  /* legal in both C and C++ */
MyEnumType y;       // legal only in C++

enum { HOMER, MARGE, BART, LISA, MAGGIE };
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming no other declaration of `color` is available, they mean the same thing. However, it is valid to provide a different definition of `color`, and `enum color` can be used to make sure the type is used.

```
enum color { red, blue, green };
color color(const char *);
enum color a = red;
```

On the second line, specifying the return type as `color` is valid, and refers to `enum color`. On the third line, the `enum` keyword is required, because `color` would otherwise refer to the function declared on the second line.

But for practical purposes, `enum color` and `color` pretty much mean the same thing.

Comment: Hi i tried your code but get an error:error: type 'main()::color' with no linkage used to declare function 'main()::color color(const char*)' with linkage [-fpermissive]|. I have no idea what it means.

Comment: @focusHard: Move the function definition outside of main (https://ideone.com/RgWBZx):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053148/type-with-no-linkage-used-to-declare-function-with-linkage

Comment: @focusHard You put this inside a function, in which case `enum color` is a function-local type that cannot be a parameter of an external function. Generally, while you are allowed to define function-local types, there are restrictions on how those types can be used. I had intended for the code in my answer to be a complete, valid translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

In the C language (as opposed to C++), to create a name `color`, you have to type `typedef enum scolor {red, blue, green} color;`, or use the definition the question contains, using `enum colour a = blue;` - otherwise, the compiler won't know what `color` is.

In C++, any `struct X`, `class Y`, or `enum Z`, will automatically alias `X` as `struct X` and `Y` as `class Y` and `Z` as `enum Z` - thus reducing the need to `typedef struct X X;`, etc (although this would still be valid, since C++ is, as a whole, backwards compatible with C).

Both forms are equally valid in C++. It's a matter of style which you prefer.